# What is the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt 3+\sqrt 5$ over $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 5)$?

Tags: field-theory, minimal-polynomials

What is the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt 3+\sqrt 5$ over $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 5)$ ?

I proved that $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 3+\sqrt 5)=\mathbb Q(\sqrt 3,\sqrt 5)\supset \mathbb Q(\sqrt 5)$, and thus that $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 3+\sqrt5 )/\mathbb Q(\sqrt 5)$ has degree $2$. Since the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt 3+\sqrt 5$ is $X^4-16X^2+4$, the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt 3+\sqrt 5$ over $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 5)$ must be a polynomial of order 2 that divide $X^4-16X^2+4$. It's roots are $\pm\sqrt{8\pm 2\sqrt{15}}$. But I tried to make all combinaisons $(X\pm\sqrt{8\pm2\sqrt{15}})(X\mp\sqrt{8\mp2\sqrt{15}})$, but I didn't get any polynomial of order $2$ in $\mathbb Q(\sqrt 5)$ that canceled $\sqrt 3+\sqrt 5$. Where is my mistakes ?

Comment: Hint: its conjugate is $\sqrt5-\sqrt3$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $\sqrt3\notin k=\Bbb Q(\sqrt5\,)$, the minimal polynomial for $\sqrt3$ over $k$ is $x^2-3=f(x)$. Clearly, then, the minimal polynomial for $\sqrt3+\sqrt5$ is $f(x-\sqrt5\,)=(x-\sqrt5\,)^2-3=x^2-2\sqrt5x+2$.

I know this wasn’t your strategy, but it is the quickest way to get the minimal polynomial.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Is it possible anyway to conclude with my method ?

Comment: I think that, following @DHMO’s lead, you should have written the various conjugates of $\sqrt3+\sqrt5$ in the form $\pm\sqrt3\pm\sqrt5$

Comment: It's strange since we know that the minimal polynomial is unique and if $p(X)$ is an annihilator polynomial the the minimal polynomial divide $p(X)$. Therefore, using my technic we should be able to conclude... no ?

Comment: Yes, yes, your strategy was sound, but: yet again: $\bigl(8+2\sqrt{15}\bigr)^{1/2}=\pm(\sqrt3+\sqrt5)$. You made things difficult for yourself by squaring $\sqrt3+\sqrt5$

Comment: Fantastic ! Thanks a lot .

Answer (score 0):

Its conjugate is $\sqrt5-\sqrt3$.

Therefore, the minimal polynomial is:

$$\begin{array}{rcl}
(x-(\sqrt3+\sqrt5))(x-(\sqrt5-\sqrt3))
&=& (x-\sqrt5)^2 - (\sqrt3)^2 \\
&=& x^2-2\sqrt5x+5-3 \\
&=& x^2-2\sqrt5x+2
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $m(x)=x^2+ax+b$ be the minimal polynomial of $\sqrt3+\sqrt5$ over $\Bbb Q(\sqrt 5)$ where $a=a_1+a_2\sqrt5$ and $b=b_1+b_2\sqrt5$ in $\Bbb Z[\sqrt5]$. Then, by substitution, we have
$$(a_2+2)\sqrt{15}+(a_1+b_2)\sqrt5+a_1\sqrt3+(5a_2+b_1+8)=0$$
with solution $a=-2\sqrt5$ and $b=2.$ Hence, $m(x)=x^2-2\sqrt5 x+2$.